# How to calculate a camera up vector in world space

Tags: java, opengl, lwjgl

I am trying to calculate the camera up vector with these variables:

```
private Vector3f targetPosition = new Vector3f(0, 0, 0);
private Vector3f camPosition = new Vector3f(0, 0, 0);
private float pitch = 20; // y rotation \\
private float yaw = 0; // x rotation \\
```

How could I achieve this?

Comment: The target position cannot be equal to the camera's position - unless you mean something else by "target".

Comment: also, what meaning does `yaw` and `roll` have if you also specify the `target`?

Comment: Normally, you would apply the modelview matrix to the vector(0, 1, 0). This sounds like a school homework question as opposed to a modern opengl situation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Up Vector in world space is just up or whatever you want to define as "up". Normally up is just a positive y:

```
private const Vector3f UP = new Vector3f(0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f);
```